# How to access input control parameters from Jasper server?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I want to create a jasper report which changes the query and add/removes additional conditons in its where clause based on the input provided by the user in the jasper server.
One option is to sql inject the querystring in the jrxml file, but that looks messy as we may have additional conditions in the where clause which may be added.
The other approach mentioned in this post [Dynamic querystring in JRXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652486/dynamic-querystring-in-jrxml) seems to be a good one.

I would like to know how can I access the control parameters in the java code passed from jasper server?

Or can I give some kind of conditional logic within the jrxml file? which checks if some of the input controls are empty then assign one query in the queryString variable and another query if other conditions are valid?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Buld a "fake" parameter named P_DYNAMIC_WHERE_CLAUSE, based on your real input parameters. For instance:

```
<parameter name="PARAM1" class="java.lang.Long">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[Real query criteria on column1]]></parameterDescription>
</parameter>
...
<parameter name="P_WHERE_CLAUSE_PARAM1" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[Computed parameter, containing the optional SQL where clause corresponding to parameter PARAM1]]></parameterDescription>
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{PARAM1} != null ? " $X{EQUAL, COLUMN1, PARAM1} "  : " "]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

and use the $P!{P_DYNAMIC_WHERE_CLAUSE} syntax in the queryString.
For instance:

```
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[SELECT /* my_jasper_report */ column1
      FROM my_table
      WHERE (1=1) 
      $P!{P_DYNAMIC_WHERE_CLAUSE} 
    ]]>
</queryString>
```